# Best method to refinish cabinets, looking at Restore-a-finish

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I am interested in restore-a-finish which sounds exactly what we need (an easy to apply quick repair) but looking at the color options there does not seem to be a very close color to ours. The color of our cabinet best falls between cherry and golden oak. For anyone familiar with repairing this type of damage What would you All recommend?  Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

[image: picture of kitchen cabinet with water damage]

Comment: Colour match does not seem like a big issue since the whole thing needs work.  Most finishes in a can are usually only good to bring back the shine, or you are leaving for good in five minutes.  If you want it to last and look good, take the time to do it right.  I cannot tell if those marks are deep or only paint/stain deep.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done right and looking nice this will not be `an easy to apply quick repair`.

The entire cabinet needs to be resurfaced.

That way it is also not so sensitive to color matching.

Follow the instructions found on the WWW how to do it.